# How can I bind the Enter key to my tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to do this for the Enter key but not the Return key:

```
root.bind('<Return>',func)
```

If you are not clear on the difference between the enter key and the return key
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enter_key

I would appreciate help, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried binding any key and printing the key code when you press the enter key?

Comment: yes i tried that and it printed "\r"

Comment: No, that would be `event.char`. I don't have an enter key on my keyboard (laptop), but try `print event.keysym`. For the return key, this prints `"Return"`, so I guess that's what you are looking for. Also, is it really such a good idea to bind something to a key many modern computers don't have anymore?

Comment: event.keysym prints a new line, and i know that this key is not available on laptops but i am trying to make a program for my descktop computer and would like to be able to use this

Comment: ahh i have just worked out that i was doing it wrong and .keysym prints KP_Enter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to find out what's the correct key binding is to create a key binding for *all* keys and printing the `keysym` of the event. Now, just hit the key you want to bind the event to and see what it prints.

```
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk()
def func(event):
    print event.keysym
root.bind("<Key>", func)
root.mainloop()
```

When pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, this will print `KP_Enter`, so your binding should be

```
root.bind('<KP_Enter>', func)
```